# calling a method in another method errors

Tags: python, oop, data-structures, linked-list

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.ref = None


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def show(self):
        if self.head is None:
            print("This linked lists is empty")
        else:
            currentnode = self.head
            while currentnode is not None:
                print(currentnode.data, end=" --> ")
                currentnode = currentnode.ref

    def addelement(self, value):
        newnode = Node(value)
        newnode.ref = self.head
        self.head = newnode

    def lenofll(self , i = 0):
        while self.head is not None:
            i = i +1
            self.head = self.head.ref
        return i
    
    def middle(self):
        i = 0
        lent = self.lenofll()
        if self.head is None:  # self.head changed to None after calling lenofll method.
            print("linked list is empty")
```

I wanted to get the length of linked lists in the middle method. But as I called `self.lenofll()`, it changed the `self.head` to `None`.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: If you are getting an error, post the full error message including the stack trace. Please provide a detailed description fo the problem you are encountering, and code to reproduce that problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, doing `self.head = self.head.ref` modifies the head. You should not make any modifications to `self.head` in a method whose job is just to *search* in the list -- without modifying anything to it.

As you can see, that method keeps looping until `self.head is not None` is not true, i.e. when `self.head` is `None`. No wonder that `self.head` is `None` after running this method!

Use a local variable for this iteration instead:

```
def lenofll(self, i = 0):
    node = self.head  # use local variable
    while node is not None:
        i += 1
        node = node.ref
    return i
```